# PHP Warning: proc_open(): CreateProcess failed, error code - 267

Tags: php, windows-server

A proc_open call like the following is failing with the above error.

```
<?php
$proc = proc_open($cmd, $ds, $pipes, '/tmp', array());
```

The command `$cmd` works correctly when executed directly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with the actual command being executed.

[Error code 267](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681382%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is *ERROR_DIRECTORY "The directory name is invalid."* and in this case simply means that the `/tmp` directory doesn't exist on the drive that the code is being run from.

Instead of `/tmp`, use `sys_get_temp_dir()` (which one can assume will always exist).

Comment: I tried to use `VersionPress` wordpress plugin, and it says the same thing. I am in Windows 10 at the moment. 
How can I resolve this issue on Windows Machine, please?

Comment: @AlexisRichard Are you talking about https://github.com/versionpress/versionpress ? It may be that you don't have write-access to the tmp directory. You could try setting the `VP_VPDB_DIR` environment variable, but I'm not really sure. You'd be best off asking the VersionPress developers, and supplying a proper error report.